# ShellExecute from within a procedure

Tags: shellexecute, procedure

i want to call this.. well as good as
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'c:\Windows\notepad.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
i can call this without issue from within a method of form1

but i just had a procedure "procedure transformdataset();" that i want to call this in and it does not recognise handle... do i just need to make this procedure a method of form1? 
how do i do that? is that the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ShellExecute needs the Window Handle.  The most straightforward solution is to pass it in to your method.  I find this a bit ugly though so, personally, I'd consider calling ShellExecute when the method returns.  If the call is optional (dependent on data), consider returning a status flag from the method that indicates whether the ShellExecute call is required.  Either way works, though.

Comment: cheers i went for the ugley version but atleast it works thanks :)

Comment: Ugly is in the eye of the beholder.  I hoped you wouldn't take it as anything other than a personal preference.  Thanks for marking this as the answer!